# Drag rotate interaction in OpenLayers 3 on Linux

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I'd like to use the OpenLayers 3 [rotation interaction](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.1.0/examples/rotation.html) on a browser running under Linux. This allows the map to be rotate by dragging whilst pressing Alt and Ctrl. This works fine on Windows, however not in Redhat 6u2 and likely other distributions as the Alt key is reserved for X-Windows drag Window behaviour.

Firstly I customized the DragRotate with `ol.events.condition.shiftKeyOnly`, which worked, but conflicted with the zoom-box functionality, i.e. draws a blue zoom box whilst rotating.

```
var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
    })],
    target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View({
        center: [-25860000, 4130000],
        zoom: 10
    }),
    interactions: ol.interaction.defaults().extend([new ol.interaction.DragRotate({
        condition: ol.events.condition.shiftKeyOnly
    })])
});
```

I'd like to retain the shift-drag for the zoom box and use some other key/combination, maybe 'R+Shift'? I've tried to customize the condition. See my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adamish/hp22v0v1/)

```
var customCondition = function(mapBrowserEvent) {
   return false; // TODO
};

var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
    })],
    target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View({
        center: [-25860000, 4130000],
        zoom: 10
    }),
    interactions: ol.interaction.defaults().extend([new ol.interaction.DragRotate({
        condition: customCondition
    })])
});
```

I can't find anything in the API about implementing custom conditions other than [ol.events](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.6.0/apidoc/ol.events.html#ConditionType) and [MapBrowserEvent](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.6.0/apidoc/ol.MapBrowserEvent.html) documentation. Using a debugger I can't find any attributes in the structure or nested originalEvent that contains a keycode etc.

- How can I implement the customCondition function to detect when a given key is pressed during the drag?
- Is there any other way of implementing a drag rotate that works in Linux

Comment: A good question. I'll try some tests and let you know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a custom condition - Ctrl + Shift:

```
ol.events.condition.custom = function(mapBrowserEvent) {
    var browserEvent = mapBrowserEvent.originalEvent;
    return (browserEvent.ctrlKey && browserEvent.shiftKey);
};

var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
    })],
    target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View({
        center: [-25860000, 4130000],
        zoom: 10
    }),
    interactions: ol.interaction.defaults().extend([new ol.interaction.DragRotate({
        condition: ol.events.condition.custom
    })])
});
```